# retardar slider con javascript jquery y html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

tengo un inconveniente con un slider que tengo en mi pagina html. el tema es que al cargar la pagina desde el arranque el slider me parece de manera vertical antes de acomodarse de manera horizontal que es la posicion predeterminada por mi persona, quisiera retardar la aparicion hasta que este carga completamente.
lo intente poniendole un $(document).ready(function).
Pero se sigue cargando desde el arranque y se sigue mostrando de manera incorrecta.
hay alguna manera de retardarlo hasta que cargue todos sus css y configuraciones en el doom? o la solucion es colocarle un preloader a la pagina para que cargue todo.

esta es la imagen
y es te s mi javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var autoplaySlider = $('#autoplay').lightSlider({
        auto:true,
        loop:true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        onBeforeSlide: function (el) {
            $('#current').text(el.getCurrentSlideCount());
        } 
      });
       $('#total').text(autoplaySlider.getTotalSlideCount());
     });
```

y este el html

```
        <ul  id="autoplay" class="cs-hidden ulmarvel" style="border-radius: 20px;">

            <!-- --------- 1--------->
            <li class="item-a">
                <!-- slider box -->
                <div class="boxmarve">

                    <!-- model -->
                    <img src="estilos/imagenes/tecno/point.png" class="model">

                    <!-- details -->
                    <div class="details">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Les agradezco un consejo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: utiliza `$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});` que esperar hasta que todo el dom carge `ready` solo espera hasta que el dom este disponible!

Comment: gracias bryro. No se porque, pero lo solucione quitandole el container de bootstrap que era el que estaba "pisando el estilo", pero probare tu consejo a ver que tal reacciona, te agradezco bryro